# Tibco sending erroneous data..?

Tags: tibco, tibco-designer

I am testing Tibco Soap requests. From the image shown below, I am able to see that I am sending the correct XML in encoded form:

[image: Sample Tibco request],

But on the receiving server, when the received data is logged, there seems to be extra XML tags whose source I cannot account for, as seen in this image:

[image: sample log screenshot].

Note the duplicate XML, in both encoded and un-encoded formats. What could be the cause of this?

Answer (score 1):

Usually that depends where the text is displayed. string variables containing (serialized) xml data will show xml tags as single chars in the content view (once you click in the field). In source view you will see the xml-encoded version (< instead of <) in order to allow a full source view to contain xml data between xml tags.

They are both the same. Usually BW does not auto-convert strings on plain mappings (except frequent translations or literal CR and LFs).